# Cache huge data in-memory

Tags: caching, elasticsearch, redis, memcached, bigdata

I am looking for an in-memory cache solution which can handle big data (<5GB). For a user inputted search term, the database (elasticsearch) will return a large amount of data which the tool will analyze and show via different webpages of the tool. Now my problem is that I want to cache this big data temporarily till the user session gets over so that I don't have to fetch it again from elasticsearch every time the user opens a new page. It will have to be in-memory because disk based will take over a minute which would be very slow.

I initially thought memcached but it has a max limit of 128MB. After reading quite a bit, Redis seems suitable but it is unclear to me whether a bunch of Redis nodes can work in tandem or not. Is it possible to set up a pool of many Redis nodes so that a suitable node will be automatically chosen on `SET` and the data returned upon `GET` without me having to specify the node?

**TL;DR**

- **Problem**: Cache big data (<5GB) in an in-memory cache
- **Possible solution**: Redis
- **Question**: Can I pool a bunch of Redis nodes so that I can fetch a key stored in any of them without specifying a particular node. I don't need to distribute my data since data for a single user will fit into the RAM of a single node.

Comment: Be sure that you're not over optimizing. 5 GB sounds like a lot of data, but it's really not that much unless it's per user. Elasticsearch `filter` results are cached by default (with some exceptions, like scripts and geo operations), so subsequent searches should be quickly returned (scored queries are not cached, except with a few exceptions starting in 1.4).

Comment: Yup 5GB is per user. But since it is a B2B tool, there would be a limited number of users. Besides, if number of users increases, I can just add more nodes since the data for a single user would still fit into the RAM of a single node. In elasticsearch, I am using scan and scroll, the results of which, I assume are not cached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Redis Cluster sounds like a good fit for your usecase!

Redis cluster provides a mechanism for data sharding by means of hash slots. These slots are equally distributed over the nodes in your cluster when setting it up.

Whenever you store a value in the cluser, the corresponding hash slot for the given key is calculated and the data is forwarded to the responsible node. And the same way you can afterwards query your data again. **So the answer to your question is certainly yes.**

However, the max value size per key is 512MB. I'm not sure if I got your storage requirement correctly. I assume 5GB is the estimated total amount over all users.

Checkout the [redis cluster tutorial](http://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).

Comment: Do note that shard selection with Redis Cluster is based on hashing the key's name (or part of it) rather than on utilization.

Comment: @Moritz no, 5GB is per user. From what I understood, the 512 MB limit is only for string datatypes but if the data is saved as a list, this limit wouldn't apply? Correct me if I got this wrong.

Comment: @ItamarHaber does this mean there is no dynamic load balancing and that I'll have to restart the cluster to add a new node? Also, in case of node failure, will my data still keep going to the failed node since that node was mapped to a particular segment of data?

Comment: No need to restart the cluster when adding a new node and there's the ability to migrate shards. There's no load balancing apart from the distribution of data according to its (hashed) key names. If you require availability, you'll need to set up (and promote) slave replicas.

Comment: Re limit - you are correct. A date structure's elements are limited in size independently, but you can have a list with 10 items, where each item is 512MB.

Comment: just a question. let's say my dataframe is about 700MB and I want to cache this. Should I chunkify it before caching it or Redis cluster knows how to distribute the data?

Answer (score 1):

You can also look into [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)(.net) / [Tayzgrid](http://www.alachisoft.com/tayzgrid/)(java) by [Alachisoft](http://www.alachisoft.com/),

Both of these solutions provide distributed caching with dynamic clustering which allows to add or remove nodes in cluster at runtime with out losing any data. Also intelligent client makes sure to refer to appropriate node to fetch/store a record against any key.